# how to change html image src by c#

Tags: c#, html, webforms

```
<img src ="~/UserControls/Vote/Images/Arrow Up.png" id = "vote-up-off" 
        runat = "server" alt ="vote up" 
class="voteupImage" style="height: 45px; width: 44px"/>
```

here  i want to change src of image for certain condition like

```
if ( a==4)
{
src  url  shuld be ......
}
else
{ 
src  url should be...
}
```

Comment: I assume you're using Webforms - I retagged to reflect this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to give an `id` name which can be used as variable:

```
<img src="~/UserControls/Vote/Images/Arrow Up.png" 
     id="VoteUpOff" 
     runat="server" alt ="vote up" 
     class="voteupImage" 
     style="height: 45px; width: 44px"
/>
```

And in your code behind you could use this variable:

```
if (someCondition)
{
    VoteUpOff.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/UserControls/foo.png");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to change the id to something without hyphens, but then it would be

```
voteUpOff.Attributes["src"] = "myImage.png";
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<img src="~/UserControls/Vote/Images/Arrow Up.png" 
         id="VoteUpOff" 
         runat="server" alt ="vote up" 
         class="voteupImage" 
         style="height: 45px; width: 44px"
    />
```

**Server-Side**

```
if (someCondition)
{
    VoteUpOff.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/UserControls/foo.png");
}
```

Keep In mind to see the changes you have to place the "img" in UpdatePanel After doing the changes Update the UpdatePanel if its UpdateMode=Conditional otherwise it'll update automatically if its Property ChildAsTriggers=True

Comment: As it's an `<img />` with `runat="server"`, then `VoteUpOff`will be of class `HtmlImage`, so you could access the property `HtmlImage.Src`, rather than using the `Attributes` array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its working for me

```
<img src="_images/<%= AssignImageURL() %>" alt="Logo" />
```

C# Method

```
protected string AssignImageURL()
{
    String ID = Convert.ToString(Session["id"]);
    ds = sq.SelectQuery("Select LogoURl from table where ID='"+ ID+"' ");
    if (Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]).Trim() != "")
        return Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]).Trim();
    else
        return "Logo.jpg";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if (someCondition)
{
    vote-up-off.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/UserControls/pic.png");
}
```

Comment: Correct, but fundamentally adds nothing that's not already covered in the other three answers.

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: Believe it or not, this actually doesn't work for me.